# Lodash retrieve index of the items from array of objects that have a boolean property equal to true

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I am a beginner with lodash i went from c# and i have used LINQ sometimes, i have learned that lodash can be used to do query linq style, but despite my attempts, cant able to get  index of the items, from array of objects that have a boolean property  equal to true in lodash. 
Can anyone help me?

My first try :

```
var indexofItemns =_.find( arrayOfItems, (item) => 
  (item.booleanProperty === true));
```

But, I have an array and i do:

```
var indexItems: number[] = [];
indexItems= _.times(
  arrayOfItems.length,
  _.find( arrayOfItems, (item) => (item.booleanProperty === true));
```

the second row does not compile neither.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same goal with pure JS.
You don't need lodash

```js
const data = [{
    booleanProperty: false
  },
  {
    booleanProperty: true
  },
  {
    booleanProperty: false
  },
  {
    booleanProperty: true
  },
  {
    booleanProperty: false
  }
];

const indexItems = data.map((item, index) => item.booleanProperty === true ? index : null).filter((item) => item !== null);


console.log(indexItems)
```

Comment: You beat me to it, your answer is basically identical to mine so I've removed it

Answer (score 1):

If you need a single index satisfying that condition, you can use `findIndex` of `es6` or `lodash`

```
data.findIndex(a=>a.booleanProperty)
```

If you need all the indexes satisfying your condition, you can either `map`  and `filter` together sequentially (as shown in [ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477194/lodash-retrieve-index-of-the-items-from-array-of-objects-that-have-a-boolean-pro/52477313#52477313)) or you can merge them to a single `reduce` to iterate only once and build your index array. here we go:

```
data.reduce((r, a, i)=> (a.booleanProperty && r.push(i), r), [])
```

```js
let data = [{"booleanProperty":false},{"booleanProperty":true},{"booleanProperty":false},{"booleanProperty":true},{"booleanProperty":false}];
    
let indexes = data.reduce((r, a, i)=> (a.booleanProperty && r.push(i), r), []);
  
  
console.log(indexes);
```